# Sharekit - sending a url link to facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, sharekit

Below is the method I'm using with Sharekit to send an image and a title to facebook. I also want to send a URL along with the facebook post. If I try

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:image url:url title:titleString];
```

I get a too many arguments error message. Does anyone have any ideas on how this should be done? thanks for any help.

```
- (IBAction)myButtonHandlerAction
    {               
                    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/"];
                NSString *titleString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"*** %@ * \n\nGet the ***** App - It's Free!", entity.name];

                UIImage *image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:entity.image] autorelease];     

                SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:image title:titleString];

                // Get the ShareKit action sheet
                SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];

                // Display the action sheet
                [actionSheet showFromBarButtonItem:barbtn animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method `-[SHKItem image:url:title:]`. So an error is being raised. Currently there is no mechanism to do what you require using *ShareKit* so you will have to customize ShareKit for your needs. You should also look at the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is a url item, with an image attached to it. If so, you can do this :

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/"] title:@"Check this link"];
[item setCustomValue:@"http://example.com/someimage.jpg" forKey:@"picture"];
[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```

I've implemented this with the latest sharekit, it works for me.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work, but this solution does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122414/sharekit-posting-linked-image-to-facebook-wall