# ShareKit - posting linked image to facebook wall

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, sharekit

( this is really the same as this question, but the answer given was not relevant

[add image and description on facebook with sharekit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542050/add-image-and-description-on-facebook-with-sharekit)
)

How do I send a link to an image with ShareKit, so that when shared, it appears like so:

[image]

Or, alternatively, can I set the FB app to always show the big icon when something is posted?

Comment: What I am seeing and read on couple of posts is FB Share Kit is not working properly..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(answering my question)

I changed the file SHKfacebook.m changing the dialog.attachment line to read:

```
dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"%@\",\"href\"
:\"%@\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"http://example.com/example.png\"
,\"href\": \"http://example.com/\"}]} ",item.title == nil ? SHKEncodeURL(item.URL) 
SHKEncode(item.title),SHKEncodeURL(item.URL)];
```

(make it one line after you paste in)

You can see there is an image url - http://example.com/example.png - which should be about 76 X 90px, and a link url - http://example.com/

You may also need to explicitly set the sharetype. I've noticed on 3G/3GS iPhones then it doesn't work unless you do this:

```
item.shareType = SHKShareTypeURL;
[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SHKFacebook * sharer = [ [ [ SHKFacebook alloc ] init] autorelease ];
SHKItem * item = [ SHKItem URL:[ NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com" ]
                         title:@"my title"
                   contentType:SHKURLContentTypeUndefined ];
item.facebookURLShareDescription = @"my description";
item.facebookURLSharePictureURI = @"http://www.userlogos.org/files/logos/pek/stackoverflow.png";
[ sharer loadItem:item ];
[ sharer share ];
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work in the latest sharekit.. It pops up the post but doesn't post....

Answer (score 0):

Here is my amendment for the answer and it can share the title, image and the description when share to facebook. Enjoy it

```
dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"%@\",\"href\":\"%@\",\"description\":\"%@\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-77BXdZj0M6o/Tr0t9pndpOI/AAAAAAAAAQ4/j3KWIE9ov1E/s1600/Blue_Eye_by_SapphiraBlue.jpg\" ,\"href\": \"%@/\"}]} ",item.title == nil ? SHKEncodeURL(item.URL) : SHKEncode(item.title),SHKEncodeURL(item.URL), @"Testing Description Comes Here", SHKEncode(SHKMyAppURL)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Or another solution comes here for editing the image and description as parameters

```
dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"%@\",\"href\":\"%@\",\"description\":\"%@\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"%@\" ,\"href\": \"%@/\"}]} ",item.title == nil ? SHKEncodeURL(item.URL) : SHKEncode(item.title),SHKEncodeURL(item.URL), item.text, item.filename, SHKEncode(SHKMyAppURL)];
dialog.userMessagePrompt = SHKLocalizedString(@"Enter your message:");
dialog.defaultStatus = @"";
```

By passing the parameters simply like this:

```
SHKItem *itemfb = [SHKItem image:@"" title:@"TITLE" url:url2];
        itemfb.shareType = SHKShareTypeURL;
        itemfb.text = @"DESCRIPTION COME HERE"; 
        itemfb.filename = @"IMAGE PATH";
        [SHKFacebook shareItem:itemfb];
```